# Markdown bug in comments with ` `

Tags: bug, comments, markdown, markdown-rendering

I just tried to write this comment:

---

You could use `$arr = explode(' ', $str);` to split `$str` by . Then you could do the same on `=` to get your key->value pairs.

---

But it chokes on [image] and formats like so:

[image]

Comment: You could use `$arr = explode(' ', $str);` to split `$str` by `​ `. Then you could do the same on `=` to get your key->value pairs.